# Installing Ubuntu from a tablet, what do I do?

Tags: installation, android

Ladies and lordships!

I'm getting a new PC tonight, which I'm very happy about, but, it doesnt have an operating System.

So, where else to go, but into Ubuntuland? Ubuntuland, right? :)

But, and this is my problem, I'll need to install the software from my android Galaxy Tab 2.

How.. do I do that? Where do I pick up the ISO file, so my new machine can find it?

I'm guessing this might be fruitful to post in the Samsung forums also, but if any1 has an idea, please fill me in.

Kind regards

Simon

Comment: he wants to use his GT2 to download Ubuntu; not install it on his GT2 @TheLordofTime ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a cool app called [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) that should be able to help you out with booting from your Android device. Your device will need to be rooted for this to work. Once you've booted into Ubuntu on your computer, you should be able to find a shortcut that will allow you to install Ubuntu on your new computer. Enjoy the new Ubuntu-powered computer!

Source: [Lifehacker Article](http://lifehacker.com/5990655/how-to-boot-into-linux-from-your-android-phone)